# Foreign characters and LDAP. What encoding/charset does LDAP expect?

Tags: php, encoding, active-directory, ldap

I am parsing XML, with `simplexml_load_string()`, and using the data within it to update Active Directory (AD) objects, via LDAP.

Example XML (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>Bìlbö Bággįnš</user>
    <user>Gãńdåłf Thê Gręât</user>
    <user>Śām Wīšë</user>
</users>
```

I firstly run an `ldap_search()` to find a single user and then proceed to change their attributes. Pumping the above values straight into AD, using LDAP, will result in some pretty mangled characters showing up.

For example: `BÃ¬lbÃ¶ BÃ¡ggÄ¯nÅ¡`

**I've tried the following functions, to no avail:**

```
utf8_encode($str);
utf8_decode($str);
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $str);
iconv("UTF-8", "T.61", $str);
```

Ideally, I don't want to do any of these string conversions. UTF-8 *should* be fine, right?!

**I've also noticed the following:**
I have printed out the values to see how they come out. curl-ing the script in CLI will show the correct characters, but web browsers show the same as AD.

**What's going on? Should I be looking at something else, eg. URL encoding?**
I'm hoping this is down to a simple mistake on my end.

**EDIT:**
I entered in these characters using AD admin GUI to see how they would come out. I can read them via LDAP fine. Correct characters are displayed when in a browser. curl-ing via CLI will show question marks instead of foreign characters. Passing one of these returned values into `mb_detect_encoding()` will return UTF-8.

I decided to immediately modify the same object by not writing in a new string, but just reversing the existing value and saving the object. This works fine - I see the correct value (reversed) in AD.

- Developing on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion - PHP 5.4.3
- Running production on: Red Hat 6 - PHP 5.4.3
- AD server: Windows 2003

**UPDATE:**
After a few months, I was unable to find the answer/solution to this problem.
In the end, I went with replacing characters to their non-accented equivalent (NOT ideal, I know).

Comment: Use `bin2hex()` on one of those values to show us the binary string values.

Comment: @deceze `bin2hex( á ) == c3a1`. I'm not sure if anything happens to the character as it gets copied and pasted around everywhere. System clipboard may corrupt/change it (?).

Comment: I guess that LDAP/AD that is a Microsoft version of LDAP is in `WINDOWS-1250` encoding as anything from Microsoft... Therefore `iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1250", $str);` should work.

Comment: It doesn't like WINDOWS-1250 - `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

Comment: is it anything to do with the php file itself does not have UTF8 encoding ? the php file accessing ldap should set it's encoding type as UTF-8?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using LDAP v3?

```
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

LDAPv3 supports UTF-8 by default, which it expects requests and responses to be in by default. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx

Comment: Are you running the LDAP script on a NIX box or a Windows box. Is it the same server that AD is configured on? What version of PHP?

Comment: Try: `iconv("UTF-8", "T.61", $str);`

Comment: Good point; I've added the requested information to the question. ...and: `Wrong charset, conversion from 'UTF-8' to 'T.61' is not allowed` :(

Comment: Try `ldap_8859_to_t61()` and `ldap_t61_to_8859`. See if that will allow you to convert

Comment: This resolved the issue I ran into. It was in the manual but i looked past is 1000 times.

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it's most likely to solve it for anyone else that has a similar problem. I've tried everything here and nothing worked :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that worked for me. Do following things:

1.) First make sure you are using LDAP protocol version 3 which is using
    "UTF-8" by default:

```
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

2.) If you want to change user's password, than make sure that "use TLS" option is set to `true` and use SSL to `false`.

```
ldap_start_tls($ldapConnection);
```

3.) I used port number `389`.

4.) Use PHP function `ldap_mod_replace` to replace user's password.

5.) Use the following function to encode your `$password`:

```
public function encodePassword($password)
{
    $password="\"".$password."\"";
    $encoded="";
    for ($i=0; $i <strlen($password); $i++){ 
        $encoded.="{$password{$i}}\000"; 
    }
    return $encoded;
}
```

6.) Use the following logic to change user's password:

```
$password="test";
if(mb_detect_encoding($password) == 'UTF-8')
{
    $password = utf8_decode($password);
}

$add=array();
$add["unicodePwd"][0] = encodePassword($password);

$result = @ldap_mod_replace($ldapConnection, $userDn, $add);
if ($result === false){
    //your action
}
else{
    //Your action
}
```

7.) Please note that function `encodePassword` will encode your
    `$password` to UTF-8 encoding. If your password is UTF-8 encoded,
    then your have to decode it before sending it to the
    `encodePassword` function. That is why I wrote the line:

```
if(mb_detect_encoding($password) == 'UTF-8')
{
    $password = utf8_decode($password);
}
```

This code worked for me when I provide german Umlauts in password: `äüößÄÜ` etc...

Comment: setting this completely solved my problems!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to add foreign characters in LDAP with two steps:

- add the user only with ASCII characters (iconv "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
- use `ldapmodify` to update the field(s) with UTF-8 characters

LDAPv3 is UTF-8, but the tool I used (from `smbldap-tools`) was not dealing with it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to mention for those stumbling across this:

If your text is already in UTF-8, then do NOT attempt to re-encode it. Note the following remarks on the doc page for [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php). Re-encoding an already encoded string will result in garbled text. Additionally, the function only allows for one specific encoding to another.

You could easily test if you need to UTF-8 encode the string by doing something like:

```
if (!preg_match('//u', $value)) {
    // do your encoding process...
}
```

Regarding the characters not showing correctly on a web page either, but they are on the CLI, make sure you are setting the correct charset in your headers:

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`