# PHP LDAP authentication pound character

Tags: php, ldap

I have an LDAP authentication problem with the pound character, I tried using:

```
$password = utf8_decode($password);
```

or

```
$password = mb_convert_encoding($_POST["password"], "UTF-8");
```

but don't work!

this is my function :

```
function authenticate($user, $password) {
    if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;
    $ldap_host_dcf = "xxxx.xx";
    $ldap_dcf = ldap_connect($ldap_host_dcf);
    ldap_set_option($ldap_dcf, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap_dcf, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    if($bind_dcf = @ldap_bind($ldap_dcf, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) { 
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "problem with the pound character"? The `#` character isn't anything special. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: I think the OP is refering to the british currency...

Comment: @heiglandreas Ha, yeah, that makes more sense.

Comment: There is an `encodePassword` method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41060909/1202807). That *might* help.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: `utf8_decode` (as well as `utf8_encode`)  only help in converting ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. So that's a very specific thing! `mb_convert_encoding` on the other hand – if not used with the third parameter – uses the default encoding you can get via `mb_internal_encoding` to decode from. Usually that's already UTF-8... Can you check with `echo bin2hex($password);` what hex-coding the password actually has? and whether that makes sense in a UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Thanks I solved.

My ldap function is correct, the problem was in the user in active direcotory!

Comment: Directory servers treat passwords as octet strings. If done correctly, passwords and therefore any special character are UTF-8 encoded by client applications before sending them. But there are many legacy applications that just send the password in their local character sets, resulting in inconsistencies and authentication issues.